# Is it possible to move an Andriod App and Account to iOS

Tags: ios

[This link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201196), makes it sound possible.

So briefly why I am asking.  I am a Note 7 owner still, I have tried 6 times now to exchange, return and even unwind my phone.  The problem is I brought from a third-party seller Diamond Wireless and not Version directly.  In talking to a friend he was like just switch the Iphone already.  My argument was my love for the Android OS and all my accounts (and games) are purchased through the Play Store, I thought I would have to re-buy all the apps but the link above hints that you may not have to.  Am I reading that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Free apps will migrate if they are found in both Google Play and the App Store.  Read below, taken from your link.  Paid apps you will have to purchase on iOS:

> Here's what gets transferred: contacts, message history, camera photos
>   and videos, web bookmarks, mail accounts, and calendars. Some of your
>   free apps will transfer if they're available on both Google Play and
>   the App Store. After the transfer completes, you can download any free
>   apps that were matched from the App Store. Any matched paid apps will
>   appear in your iTunes Wishlist.